# Как в обработчике ошибок получить ссылку из за которой возникло исключение?

Tags: php, yii2, framework

Всем привет!
Кто может подсказать как в обработчике ошибок получить ссылку из за которой возникло исключение.
К примере есть ссылка:
site.ru/a/b/c - которая является не рабочей (будет выброшено NotFoundException)
Есть обработчик ошиок actionError():

```
public function actionError()
{
    //Как вот здесь получить site.ru/a/b/c
}
```

Пробовал использовать $app->request->referrer, но это свойство возвращает последнюю удачно загруженную страницу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ура нашел!

```
Yii::$app->request->url
```

Я почему то решил что в свойстве Yii::$app->request->url  будет находится ссылка на обработчик ошибок.